# "Something might come along" vs "Something might turn up"

Tags: idioms

Which is better? As in:

> She had no money and no job. No place to stay, either. Hope dies last, though. Something ...

Or, if you wish to rephrase the whole thing, be my guest.

Answer (score 1):

> "Something might come along" vs "Something might turn up"

If something "comes along" you're more likely to be unimpressed by its quality.  "Coming along" suggests a kind of drifting nature, "taking what comes".

(So "something amazing turned up" would sound more normal than "something amazing came along".)

If these were the only two options, then I'd suggest "turn up" for higher hopes with "come along" for more modest ones.

> Or, if you wish to rephrase the whole thing, be my guest.

If you're looking for writing advice, that's a whole different site--and would need much more context!

https://writers.stackexchange.com/

But one thought: "hope dies last" can be a bit of a "punchline".  Once you've said it, if you back out into an explanation of how this character is holding onto a feeble shred of hope, you've given it away and will have a tough time recovering.

> *She had no money and no job. No place to stay, either. But something might turn up. She logged into stackexchange.com again...*
>
> *Hope dies last.*

:-P